# is there a default url for auth login in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

The default auth system in laravel has a default url?

I've tried: `/user/login` or `/login` none worked, same with register

or should I define a route for them? they kinda implicit

Comment: Did you run `php artisan make:auth` beforehand?

Comment: Here's the documentation on [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication) in case you missed it

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to go through  the [laravel.com](http://laravel.com) documentation.
and yes you have to use `php artisan make:auth` command into the application to use laravel default authentication functionality.